# Meaning of employed

Tags: usage

Is the usage of employed incorrect in the following sentence?

> A little rail road engine was **employed** by a station yard for doing small pieces of work.

According to my book it is better to use **used** in place of **employed**. But I think employed is also correct because its meaning is **to use something** as in the following sentence

> Official data was employed to obtain final results.

Comment: It's fine to use _employed_  to mean _used_, though in that particular context it does sound a little as though the engine was being paid a wage for the work!

Comment: I frequently employ a broom to sweep the floor of my workspace (crumbs, scraps of paper, etc), and I do not issue it with a paycheque each month.

Answer (score 0):

Working class people somtimes ***use*** a vacuum cleaner to clean the inside of their house or apartment.

Hiwever, wealthy individuals ***employ*** someone to use a vacuum cleaner on behalf of the wealthy person.

It is grammatically correct to write, "I ***employed*** a screwdriver to pry the lid open", but you will sound like an aristocrat.

British and American children know how to  "***use***" a pencil, but only 78 year-old polititians and 64 year-old theoretical physicists know how to ***employ*** a writing utencil.

Comment: Spelling:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sometimes https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/however https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/politician https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/utensil